# How do I make `ls` show file sizes in megabytes?

Tags: linux, ls

What commands do I need for Linux's `ls` to show the file size in MB?

Answer (score 1018, accepted):

`ls -l --block-size=M` will give you a long format listing (needed to actually see the file size) and *round file sizes up* to the nearest MiB.

If you want MB (10^6 bytes) rather than MiB (2^20 bytes) units, use `--block-size=MB` instead.

If you don't want the `M` suffix attached to the file size, you can use something like `--block-size=1M`. Thanks [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas) for suggesting this.

If you simply want file sizes in "reasonable" units, rather than *specifically megabytes*, then you can use `-lh` to get a long format listing and **human readable** file size presentation. This will use units of file size to keep file sizes presented with about 1-3 digits (so you'll see file sizes like `6.1K`, `151K`, `7.1M`, `15M`, `1.5G` and so on.

The `--block-size` parameter is described in the man page for ls; `man ls` and search for `SIZE`. It allows for units other than MB/MiB as well, and from the looks of it (I didn't try that) arbitrary block sizes as well (so you could see the file size as a number of 429-byte blocks if you want to).

Note that both `--block-size` and `-h` are GNU extensions on top of [the Open Group's `ls`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/ls.html), so this may not work if you don't have a GNU userland (which most Linux installations do). The `ls` from GNU Coreutils 8.5 does support --block-size and -h as described above. Thanks to [kojiro](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/5377/kojiro) for pointing this out.

Comment: A difference maybe worth noticing: `--block-size=M` cause a `M` suffix to be displayed next to the size, and you can use `--block-size=1M` to omit it. It may be worth mentioning as well that you need GNU ls for that (most non-embedded Linux systems will have GNU ls).

Comment: Would this be GNU `ls`? [Standard `ls`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/ls.html) has no such argument. With the [xsi extension](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/help/codes.html#XSI) `ls` has the `-s` flag, which makes it report the number of blocks, but there is no standard flag `--block-size`.

Comment: @kojiro GNU ls does have `--block-size` as of coreutils 8.5, which is what's installed on my Debian Squeeze system. Since the question was explicitly for Linux and did not specify anything else, I'll admit I assumed a userland centered around GNU coreutils. I have updated the answer to clarify this. (Besides, Open Group ls doesn't seem to have -h either. `:)`)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: `ls -l --block-size=Z` (as well as `ZB`, `Y`, and `YB`) gives the following error (for the corresponding `--block-size` argument): `ls: --block-size argument `Z' too large`. If I read `ls(1)` correctly, `Z` is 1000^7, `ZB` is 1024^7, `Y` is 1000^8, and `YB` is 1024^8. I have no intuition on such large numbers -- what do you think, is there an overflow on the application level (i.e., some C variable) or is it beyond the system architecture?

Comment: @EmanuelBerg, 1000^7 (10^21) is greater than 2^64 (which is ~10^19.27)

Comment: This returns `ls: illegal option -- -` for me on OSX Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: @Tom As it says in the final paragraph of the answer, `--block-size` is a GNU extension. I suspect that Mac OS X doesn't use GNU `ls`.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I can confirm that the --block-size flag causes an error on Mac OS X 10.13.2, but that ls -lh does work.

Comment: `du -sm *` is another (faster to type) way to get something similar.  But `-m` isn't POSIX-standard either.  (`-k` is, so you can `du -sk *` even on a system with only POSIX options).

Comment: @PeterCordes Sure, but OP asked specifically for a solution using `ls`.

Comment: Also, AFAIU, `ls -s --block-size=K` shows the file size rounded up *to the nearest block* (*disk size*), whereas `ls -lh` does not, and shows the factual *contents* size (for example, 396 KB vs 393 KB)

Comment: For macOS, we have the GNU `coreutils` package with Homebrew and the command `gls` (prefixed with `g` to avoid conflicts). Works like a charm

Comment: Note that this won't work at all on a thinly provisioned VM.

Comment: @AlexJohnson It should work fine if your VM has a GNU userland, as already stated in the answer.

Comment: Why is this long-winded, impossible to recall, overly verbose switch preferable to the simple, consistent and widely used across commands "human" readable switch: -h

Comment: @RickO'Shea Because passing `-h` to `ls` doesn't guarantee that sizes are printed in megabytes. Since the question specifically asked how to make `ls` show file sizes in megabytes, suggesting to use `-h` provides an answer to the question only for a subset of the possibilities. That said, there's an answer specifically suggesting `ls -lh` if you prefer that.

Answer (score 708):

`ls -lh` gives human readable file sizes, long format.

`ls` from the GNU coreutils package gives sizes in binary byte format in this case, e.g. Mebibyte (MiB), [which is strongly endorsed by IEEE and CIPM](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte) **instead** of Megabyte (MB).

It uses k, M, G, and T suffixes (or no suffix for bytes) as needed so the number stays small, e.g. `1.4K` or `178M`.

`-h` is a GNU coreutils extension, not baseline POSIX.

Note that this doesn't answer the question exactly as asked.  If you want sizes strictly in MiB even for small or gigantic files, [Michael Kjörling's answer does that for GNU coreutils `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64148/how-do-i-make-ls-show-file-sizes-in-megabytes/64150#64150).

Comment: That will print file sizes in GB for anything bigger than just under 1.0 GiB (I believe).

Comment: yeah, sorry, i thought that's what was wanted (as opposed to bytes).

Comment: @Dason I didn't downvote this, either, for precisely the reason you state as well as the fact that for most semi-large files, `-h` does meet the OP's stated requirement quite nicely. But I also didn't upvote, because as I said it doesn't really *answer the question*. As for "phrasing it wrong", well, the OP has been on SE (ServerFault, StackOverflow and SuperUser) at least since late 2009 - early 2010, so certainly can hardly be considered a newcomer to the site.

Comment: Upvoted. "This doesn't answer the (MB) question" is a perfectly valid statement but this answer has only increased the usefulness of this SO page since this answer is in same context. I only came to this page looking for a solution to generic "show dates in human readable form" requirement and `h` is far easier to write than `--block-size=M`

Comment: "human-readable" is kind of ironic. Who uses `ls -l` at all if not humans? :p

Comment: @Blauhirn not really, often times the output of commands are piped as input for other commands

Comment: @chengyang: parsing `ls -l` output is the wrong way to do things, 99% of the time.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls.  That 1% is being generous, and is pretty much limited to one-liners you write interactively for one-time use, not a script you're going to use repeatedly on unknown filenames.

Comment: @Blauhirn: sometimes you want an exact size in bytes you can copy/paste or compare with another number, instead of a rounded size you can read quickly.  But I see what you mean, it is a bit funny.

Comment: Under macOS, the unit for the sizes is a power of 2, not 10. So it is MiB instead of MB. I prefer the powers of 10.

Comment: @phil294, I have scripts that use ls -l to get size and other details and they need a consistent size format so that all sizes can be treated as equivalent. Over time with a system and automation, the computer ends up reading itself more than any human does.